# Jquery UI autocomplete with value label pairs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I would like to set the source of autocomplete to the one that can have value/label pairs as described in their documentation here

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

They say that

> ```
> An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
> ```
>
> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will
>   be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If
>   just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you
>   provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the
>   label.

In my code I have

html

```
 <input type="text" id="testBox" name="testBox" maxlength="70"/>
```

in my js

```
var catsArr = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    var cat = {
                        label: "grey " + i,
                        value: i
                    };
                    catsArr.push(cat);
                }

                //tie the autocomplete to the box
                $("#testBox").autocomplete({ source: catsArr });
```

But somehow, when the user starts typing the word `grey`, nothing shows up....What am I missing?

Comment: Did you place your code inside of a `$(document).ready(...)` handler? http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/24/

Comment: turns out the project I was working on didn't include the entire jquery ui. I assumed it did, because it used some jquery ui controls.